# Extracting useful/readable content from a website

Tags: php, curl, web, screen-scraping

I am working on a application that needs to scrape a part of a website the user submits. I want to collect useful and readable content from the website and definitely not the whole site. If I look at applications that also do this ([thinkery](http://thinkery.me) for example) I notice that that they somehow managed to create a way to scrape the website, try to guess what useful content is, show it in a readable format and they do that pretty fast.

I've been playing with cURL and I am getting pretty near the result I want but I have some issues and was wondering if someone has some more insights.

```
    $ch = curl_init('http://www.example.org');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

    // $content contains the whole website
    $content = curl_exec($ch);

    curl_close($ch);
```

With the very simple code above I can scrape the whole website and with preg_match() I can try to find div's with the class, id or properties which contains the string 'content', 'summary' et cetera.

If preg_match() has result I can fairly guess that I have found relevant content and save this as the summary of the saved page. The problem I have is that cURL saves the WHOLE page in memory so this can take up a lot of time and resources. And I think that doing a preg_match() over such a large result can also take up a lot of time.

Is there a better way to achieve this?

Comment: `preg_match` to find the content from a string that contains an entire HTML page? You're joking right? If you're worried about memory so much, `allow_url_fopen` and load the page directly with `DomDocument::loadHTMLFile`

Comment: Thats probably why I'm looking for help, I know it will break on tags not closed properly and that it is one of the slower functions. // thanks, will try that out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried the DomDocument::loadHTMLFile as One Trick Pony suggested (Thanks!)

```
    $ch = curl_init('http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17180043/extracting-useful-readable-content-from-a-website');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    $content = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    $doc = new DOMDocument();
    @$doc->loadHTML($content);

    $div_elements = $doc->getElementsByTagName('div');

    if ($div_elements->length <> 0)
    {
        foreach ($div_elements as $div_element) 
        {
            if ($div_element->getAttribute('itemprop') == 'description')
            {
                var_dump($div_element->nodeValue);

            }
        }
    }
```

The result for above code is my question here on this page! Only thing left to do is find a good and consistent way to loop through or query the divs and determine if it is useful content.

Comment: That's good, but I think you should use the `textContent` property. And `libxml_use_internal_errors(true)` to suppress errors.  Also check out [xpath](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domxpath.php), you want to query for text nodes only - `//div/text()[normalize-space()]`